# What is the difference between these two c# abstract classes?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, object-oriented-analysis

So I was following a c# tutorial the otherday (still a begginer) and I saw how the class ATMState was defined:

```
public abstract class ATMState
{
    private ATM atm;

    public ATM Atm
    {
        get { return atm; }
        set { atm = value; }
    }
    private int dummyCashPresent = 1000;

    public int DummyCashPresent
    {
        get { return dummyCashPresent; }
        set { dummyCashPresent = value; }
    }

    public abstract string GetNextScreen();
}
```

To be honest, I find those declaraions rather confusing, so I decided to redo it in my own way:

```
public abstract class ATMState
    {
        public ATM Atm { get; set;  }
        public int DummyCashPresent { get; set; }

        public ATMState()
        {
            DummyCashPresent = 1000;
        }
        public abstract string GetNextScreen();
    }
```

What is the difference? Which one is better and why?

Comment: This question is much more appropriate for `CodeReview`

Comment: Is your question specifically about adding a constructor or the auto properties?

Comment: Second one is better, just because its more readable. Otherwise, there's no differrence in terms of Performance, OOPs concepts or anything. They both going to compile to same MSIL

Comment: Also note that C# didn't always have auto-properties. The tutorial might very well be from that time :)

Comment: "Better" is a loaded word. If it means "being shorter while retaining the functionality", your second snippet wins. If it means "being compilable with C# 2.0", first snippet wins hands-down.

Comment: If you extend your class in the future, add some logic in property-setter and properts-getter, or need to acces the raw property value form inside your class without going through any property-logic THEN you need the property with backing field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference?

You're using "automatic properties", the sample code is not. Perhaps the sample was written before automatic properties were introduced to C#.

> Which one is better and why?

Generally automatic properties are better: more compact code is less to read and understanding. If you have no logic to put in the getter or setter you should be using automatic properties.

However, currently<sup>1</sup> you cannot set a breakpoint on either the getter or setter of an automatic property, thus to be able to track accesses one sometimes need to break out with an explicit backing field.

---

<sup>1</sup> I believe this will change in VS2015.